# I am happy with my job but do they know what they are doing..?

Tags: developer

I am working for a big IT company as Web developer and it's my dream job.

However there's one problem - they hire me for a .NET position knowing that I was not a .NET developer, and to make matters worse, they put me in charge of a Sitecore project - a CMS which even advanced .NET developer need a learning curve to work with. I asked my boss how long it took to find the right developer for them and he told me it took a very long time and a lot of interviews.

Here's my question: Why did they put a guy like me, who has worked mainly with PHP and Python and is still technically a junior with approx 2 year experience, in a .NET position knowing the fact that I didn't code in .NET?

Comment: That's the problem I have deadlines, and it's very strefull I am on my 3  month probation and I feel like it's already over after 4 weeks in my position they already asked me to add features in the solution and to do a full sitecore migration.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I think I have confidence issue I am guy who didn't even finish High School at 15yo I was a High School drop out and now I am working with people who have a good education and developer with years of experiences.

Comment: Ask the company.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the project (i.e. how much custom functionality needs to be built), a Sitecore project may not actually involve much .NET dev work. It may be largely wiring up a content model to markup elements via the Sitecore admin platform.

Comment: No that's the probleme I need to do big .NET dev exemple I need to find a way to do 301 redirect with regex expression by the aliases in Sitecore.

Comment: Are you able to do the work? Do you feel you're not the right person for the task you are being given? Not sure I see the problem as you say you like the job "it's my dream job"

Comment: I'd rather higher a good Python/PHP developer than a bad .NET developer regardless of the task. There will be a learning period for both of them, but one will be better in the long-run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Converting comments to answer since people always yell at me for that)

You clearly came off as intelligent in the interview and capable of learning something given enough time. Possibly this 'sitecore' project is something that needs work to be done on it, but with no definite deadlines, so its more appropriate for someone who is still learning due to the lack of deadline, then once you have ramped up and are capable of this "advanced .NET", then they will have confidence that you can work on other things that have stricter deadlines. (all just possibilities)

Quite honestly, companies know what they are getting when they ask for a junior/entry level position. I've worked at 3 different places and it ALWAYS took me 1-2 months to start feeling comfortable and then another month or so to know a good portion of the system. If they are pressuring you more than is physically possible for you within 40 hours a week (or whatever your schedule is without overtime), then simply talk to your manager and let him know you need time to ramp up, you don't want to wait until you miss all your deadlines.

Confidence comes as you gain experience. In a month or two you will realize that your not half bad and actually just as good as many people who have been there for a long time. Forget your background and stop comparing your education to others, simply focus on the work you have to do and admire the work you have done;nothing good comes from comparing your education levels.

Answer (score 4):

What feedback have you been getting from your manager on your performance so far? Generalizing from your specific situation, there are three possibilities here:

1. Your manager is telling you "you're doing fine". In that case, read TheOneWhoPrograms's answer and relax (a little bit).
2. Your manager is telling you there are certain aspects of your work you need to improve. Hopefully, what to do here is obvious!
3. You're not getting any real feedback from your manager. In this case, the first thing to do is to schedule some time with your manager to discuss your performance; hopefully that will result in you becoming aware whether situation 1 or 2 applies. If you're still not getting any useful feedback from your manager, *this is a problem with your manager, not you*, but it may be worthwhile reading [in a company without 1-on-1s or structured feedback, what can I do to understand how I can improve my performance?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32242/in-a-company-without-1-on-1s-or-structured-feedback-what-can-i-do-to-understand)

Comment: My manager alway say it's part of the training with giving me real feedback on my work,he doesn't care to much, I am on my own nobody helps me. I am at the stage of asking stupid question on stackoverflow like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358484/redirect-in-a-sitecore-solution-noob because my back is against the wall

Comment: If as a junior developer, you're 1) not getting the support you need from senior devs and 2) not getting good feedback on your performance, then I'd argue that this isn't your dream job, whatever it may seem like.

Comment: Well the way I see it is I never tought I will get that far in this Industrie without a education like I said earlier thats why for me it's my dream job to be in a big company like this...